# Cause of long term inflation in the United States

Tags: inflation

Does the US government have a policy of printing money? If so what is this number called, who decides what it is, and where can I find it? If not what is the cause of our *long term* inflation? (I'm aware of the impact that the Fed's open market operations have on short term inflation)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about macroeconomics, not mathematical/computational finance

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a policy but I think one can view how much money is in circulation (I.e. Money being printed) by the Monetary Base. It can be found and downloaded using FRED. As for long term inflation one can use the CPI which is based from a basket of goods. I believe the #1 rising good in the CPI is housing/rent prices.